# Applying the max() function on a user entered integer list does not return the maximum?

Tags: python, max, min

I want to find the maximum and minimum in a user provided list of numbers.

```
value = input("Please enter an integer separated by commas. :")

i = value.split(',')

value1 = max(i)
value2 = min(i)

print("max =", value1)

print("min =", value2)
```

Executing the code and entering `1,2,4,36,5` results in

```
Please enter an integer separated by commas. :1,2,4,36,5
max = 5
min = 1
```

Why does the `max()` function return `5` instead of `36`?

Comment: You're comparing strings, not numbers.

Comment: What does `print("5" > "36")` print?

Answer (score 1):

You should cast all the `i` elements to int

```
value = input("Please enter an integer separated by commas. :") #input 1,2,4,36,5

i=[int(el) for el in value.split(',')]
value1 = max(i)
value2 = min(i)
print("max =", value1)
print("min =", value2)
```

OR

```
i = [int(el) for el in input("Please enter an integer separated by commas. :").split(',')] #input 1,2,4,36,5

value1 = max(i)
value2 = min(i)
print("max =", value1)
print("min =", value2)
```

Output

```
max = 36
min = 1
```

The original code made that elements in `i` as strings `['1', '2', '4', '36', '5']` so they just need to be changed to ints and that made the `min` and `max` functions to work properly.

Comment: Don't use the same variable `i` for the iteration variable and result, it's confusing.

Comment: Tnx for that I'm changing it.

Answer (score 1):

They are in string format that's why. Just map them to integer.

```
value = input("Please enter an integer separated by commas. :")

i=list(map(int, value.split(','))) #<---- Here
print(i)

value1 = max(i)
value2 = min(i)

print("max =", value1)

print("min =", value2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert it into integer to get proper results

```
value = input("Please enter an integer separated by commas. :")

i=value.split(',')
i = [int(x) for x in i]
value1 = max(i)
value2 = min(i)

print("max =", value1)

print("min =", value2)

OR

value = input("Please enter an integer separated by commas. :")

i=[int(x) for x in value.split(',')]

value1 = max(i)
value2 = min(i)

print("max =", value1)

print("min =", value2)
```